# Using raster calculator to show multiples of particular value?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, raster-calculator

How do I use raster calculator so that the new raster only shows multiples of 128?

I'm not sure what the expression should be.

Comment: It might be useful to understand the purpose. What is the input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
Con(Con(**input_raster**,Mod(**input_raster**,128))==0,**input_raster**)
```

Let's break this apart:

The inner **Con** statement takes your **input raste**r as a conditional raster and returns **its** **modulus** against **test value** (in this case 128). The Mod function **returns zero where the number is divisible by your test value**, If not it returns the original value. **Be careful with this.**

The outer Con statement takes the result from the inner Con and checks if it is equal to zero, then returns the original values (multiples of 128) if true.

Example:

**Input Raster**
[image]

**Inner Con Results** - Note how values not divisible by 128 are treated.
[image]

**Outer Con Results**
[image]

Comment: (+1) The two uses of `con` are redundant.  In fact, an alternative might be better. `SetNull(Mod(**input**, 128)!=0, **input**)` may be closer to what was desired.